# Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. after screen off

Tags: android, admob

I noticed I get the following messages after the screen has been off:

```
I/Ads﹕ Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

I have the following code inside `onResume`:

```
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
    }
```

I stepped the code and it does get called just fine. It also works just fine if I get out of the activity and back in, the only issue appears to be when coming back after the screen goes off.

Anyone else with this issue?

Thanks.

EDIT: The code I use to create the adview and request

```
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(id);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    layout.addView(adView);
    createAdRequest();
```

The code of `createAdRequest()`:

```
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    builder.addKeyword(somekeyword);
    AdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I have noticed something else that is odd, I sometimes call `createAdRequest` again if I notice the keyword has changed, after I make that call the ads seem to stop refreshing as well but this time I don't see any visibility messages, I just don't see anymore requests until I call `createAdRequest` again.

Comment: You should include how you declare your `AdView` and initialize it.

Comment: Have you created your account recently? I take some time to show the ads in the beginning :)

Comment: My account is probably less than a month old but it is displaying ads fine, it just an issue when the screen goes off and also after calling `createAdRequest` after having called it the first time.

Comment: I confirmed that the same error happens even when running the ad sample code provided with the Google Play Services SDK, so this is definitely not due to your code and looks like a nasty bug in the ads code. What I don't know is whether this is device-dependent.

Comment: I tested using a different device and the problem was not reproduced, so this appears to be device-dependent.

Answer (score 12):

Did you add code to your onPause and onDestroy as well?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adView.resume();
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. And through debugging I made sure they were being called.

Comment: This solution worked for me (but 3 months have passed since the question was asked). I'm using the current Google Play Services ads. Without the adview.pause() I got 'Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.' plus 20% cpu while app was minimized in background. With the pause, no cpu and no logcat spam (from my app). I'm guessing Google fixed the bug, which caused it not to work for Brent below.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem in OP.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I am nothing if not persistent. I tested with this and as a caveat I have been using these flags the whole time. I haven't removed the flags but now with this broadcast receiver it works properly and seems to isolate the issue even more. I will explain.

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | // In onCreate
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

First of all I already had the receiver for another purpose. And as you can see my flags turn my screen back on but I also have a mechanism that will start the activity for me if needed(Which will need to be tweaked now because of this bug). So the fact that this works as is with all of my other mentioned mechanisms seems to imply a timing issue where AdView checks for the screens status once then doesn't check after it is back on. This was my original suspicion but as you can see the onRecieve method returns void so I can't take responsibility. Not sure if I can completely blame the Author of AdView either since I have seen some weird behavior from this intent before. It might even be a problem with the Activitys' ability to handle the intent too.

Anyway sorry if I am rambling the take away here is that I implemented the receiver to finish the activity when the screen is turned off. And I don't personally worry about starting it back up but if you need to then I added a comment to the code for that too.

[Edit] I will make this a little clearer for the most likely scenario of the Activity context. I was using a Service so that is why mine looked different. I haven't tested this one but it should work the same except I am not sure how you would check if the activity can be finished. Not even sure if that matters. My tested working code will be in my edits though if you need them as a reference.

[Edit] I did end up using this in the Activity context and it worked as expected. If the KeyGuard is not secure. Read comments for full story.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ScreenReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        receiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Got " + intent.getAction());
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                // context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyActivity.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was this reply meant for a different post?

Comment: No. I left out the adView stuff, but this is essentially what I used to force the ad to continue refreshing when the screen is turned back on. Basically it seems to depend on the Activity lifecycle or the activiy lifecycle is where the screen cycling off/on is being misinterpreted. The google forum link from my previous answer kind of goes into the role that the AdView could be playing in this. I agree that this is far from ideal but I was only able to dig so far into the lifecycle before I was blocked by abstraction. But this did work it is just acinine that it is the only thing

Comment: that has worked for me. It will force a complete refactor of how the activity lifecycle(start and stop at least) are handled by the dev.

Comment: Honestly I hope there is a better answer out there. But for me and presumably other people out there this might be the only workaround until something gets fixed.

Comment: I did notice , at least in the emulator, that turning off the screen causes SCREEN_ON to be fired off first then SCREEN_OFF. This doesn't affect me but will mean that others will need to address this by having some kind of check to see if the activity is already running before starting it again on this event. Or just let the system handle it by using the appropriate manifest property.

Comment: Sorry, I take back what I said about dismissing the keygaurd. I is a factor. I forgot that I was still using that flag. And when I took it out it stopped working for me. So if you need your ad to show ontop of  the keyguard then you need the flags that I already mention(hopefully you can decide if certain ones are not needed by you but the DISMISS and SHOW flags will be required) and you will need to address the lifecycle bug.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much time into this. I'll look into this and see if it helps. For now I'm just forcing a refresh every 60 seconds on a timer.

Comment: I am assuming you are not trying to display ontop of a keygaurd. But I just realized that the DISMISS flag does not dismiss a secure keygaurd and the AdView still breaks during the refresh cycle. I updated the google thread to see if this can be addressed since it seems to point more definitively to a break in the AdView refresh cycle.

Comment: May I ask how you are forcing a refresh with a timer? I have an AdListener that listens for failed loads and does a new loadAd after 3 seconds. But I just realized that it is not being called when the refresh cycle "decides" that the ad is not visible. Maybe that could be the fix to the lifecycle.

Comment: That is very odd that using a timer works since this seems to imply that it wouldn't  
  public void a(z paramz, long paramLong)
  {
    if (this.kY)
    {
      da.w("An ad refresh is already scheduled.");
      return;
    }
    da.u("Scheduling ad refresh " + paramLong + " milliseconds from now.");
    this.kX = paramz;
    this.kY = true;
    cz.pT.postDelayed(this.kW, paramLong);
  }

Comment: I'm just doing an adRequest every sixty seconds. When the adview internal timer is working fine mine, my adRequest just gets a already loading error. When it isn't working fine my adRequest appears to work fine. Also I had a bunch of other issues in my code, not really related to this one but basically I was calling pauseTimers on a webview and apparently that applies to all webviews, including the adview.

Comment: I tried it and it appears that when the internal timer is working fine is always the one time immediately following the new adRequest. I already mentioned this on the other thread. As I suspected I am getting a couple refresh aborts after I try to adRequest again after the one that worked. This is what I wanted to avoid but it is definitely preferable to killing the activity. I just hope it doesn't set off any flags.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. In my case the size of the banner (adSize) was greater than the available screen area. Make sure you do not have conflicting layouts.

Comment: If that is the case, it would say in the log.

Comment: this is the best answer, for me it was the other way around, the ad was to small ! haha, but thank mate.

Answer (score 1):

Admob will not refresh unless the ad is visible to user. Obviously when your phone turns off no one can see ads, thus there is no reason for Admob to request another ad.

I personally faced the same problem a couple of times. Once I was placing AdView bellow a ListView. The AdView was not visible until the list was scrolled to the bottom, therefore Admob was constantly logging **"Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad."**

Another time, I had no internet connection and the same message was continuously being logged.

Comment: I also suffering from same issue...what is the ultimate solution of it??

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try this approach I think it will pay off. I have been troubleshooting this all day. I should hope that I have a good grasp on it by now. I pasted the relevant part of the post the has the approach. Of course the onResume should be infered. For instance I am going to simply move the ad creation from the onCreate method. If you were using xml to define your ad obviously you would need to change to strictly code.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/jz-ZQh86lm0

The only way I could have the log stay silent was to remove the entire ad in onPause and add it again in onResume.

If I added the below lines everything works fine, but since this is not the recommended approach then it would be great if the timer was stopped when calling onPause.

```
admobAdView.pause();
((LinearLayout)admobAdView.getParent()).removeView(admobAdView);
admobAdView.destroy();
admobAdView = null;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. But I did try it with the added step of disabling the KeyGuard with KeyGuardLock first. Because I am showing my ad on top of the keygaurd screen. So that eliminates that as a factor. And I already eliminated all of my other theories. So that leaves just the screen cycling off/on by itself. Also I am not using keywords so I can't comment on that.